# Display simple XML data into an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, xml, load

I'm sorry if this is a very basic question but I'm really stuck here and I don't have much time.
So I created an xml file with data in it and want to display it in html using javascript, but all I get is a blank page. This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<text>
    <content>  a random text </content>
</text>
```

and that's my html file
    
    
     xml

```
    <script>
        document.write("begin");
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera,         Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","text.xml",false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

        var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("text");
        document.write(x[0].getElementsByTagName("content")    [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Maybe it uses httpRequest so it needs a server, but I tried apache and it did not work.

edit: I opened the console in chrome and it says the error is in the line `xmlhttp.send();` the error says "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

edit:it worked on mozilla, but doesn't in chrome

Answer (score 1):

Open your browser's developer tools. Turn to the console. Look at the error messages.

---

You never define `i` so you will get a reference error on `document.write(x[i]`

Comment: thanks, i opened the console it says the error is in 18 which is "xmlhttp.send();" the error "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource." i think because the file is in the same folder as the page

Comment: You need to use the absolute URL to reach text.xml, as in `http://yourwebsite.com/path/to/test.xml`

Comment: @user3171173 — That error means you need to use a web server. Many web browsers don't let you use XMLHttpRequest without HTTP. You'd already noticed that and said you were using Apache in the question. That would fix it.

Comment: thanks guys, it works now on both browsers, sorry for this question.